# how to make background colored button touchable or appear to clickable in android

Tags: android, button, background-color, imagebutton

i'm using simple button with its background colored as like -

```
android:background="#FF58585A"
```

but now it'll not appear to touchable or clickable can anyone help me how i make this button touchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to add selector (in your drawable folder) as your background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/normal" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/normal"/>
</selector>
```

Your values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="normal">#FF58585A</color>
    <color name="pressed">#ffffff</color> // what ever pressed value u want
</resources>
```

Then set this selector as your button background

```
    android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
```

Comment: you means i'll make a xml file in drawable folder named as btn_selector right? but when i'm make it as btn_selector.xml file in my drawable folder then it'll show the error that colortype not allowed at drawable.

Comment: Ohh yeah you can make color reference inside your colors.xml then add reference eg:android:drawable="@color/needed_color"

Comment: Thnks Zeal but when i'm putting these above xml file then errors are coming in color.xml error is- Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix and in btn_selector.xml error is-error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/pressed'). plz help me

Comment: Opps sorry i missed out closing "/" in color.xml resource tag :( ... m on mistake spree :( edited my answer